# Redux-form: Can't get children from Field component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, children

I'm trying to render a select, and want to be able to do something like this to add options:

```
<Field component={RenderSelect} name="subjects" label="Subjects">
        <option value="maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="english">English</option>
</Field>
```

I have a createRenderer function:

```
const createRenderer = render => ({input, name, label, children}) => {
  return (
    <div key={name}>
    <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
    {render(input, name, children)}
    </div>
  )
},
```

and my RenderSelect looks like this:

```
const RenderSelect = createRenderer((input, name, label, children) => {
    return (
      <select name={name} {...input}>
      {children}
      </select>
    )
})
```

I was under the impression that I could just destructure the `children` prop off the Field like I do for `input`, `name`, `label`, etc, although this does not seem to work. When I run the code, no options appear in my select, and an inspection of the DOM verifies that there are no options. Any help would be much apprecited. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you not just use the default `select'? From what I see it'll do everything you want it to. - https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/simple/

Comment: Well, the thing is, this was just a simple example. In the future, I am going to expand upon it, and things will get much more comples, and so I will need a custom select component. It is true that in the example I wrote in the post, the only benefit of using Field over select is that I don't have to write boilerplate for the labels, but that will likely change in the future. Besides, I am sure knowing how to pass children from my Field will  be useful for other things as well.

Comment: You should be able to pass a prop named children to Field and it'll pass it on to renderSelect. See # 3 - https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/field.md/

Comment: How do you mean? Just something like this?`<Field component={RenderSelect} children name="subjects" label="Subjects">
        //Options here
        </Field>`? That didn't work.

Comment: `children={}` where `{}` is the children object (JSX in your case) you want to be passed to your renderSelect. I haven't had a chance to test this, pulling it up now. But that's what the docs say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove your label parameter

```
const RenderSelect = createRenderer((input, name, children) => {
    return (
        <select name={name} {...input}>
            {children}
        </select>
    )
});
```

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting what exactly it is I want (maybe my question wasn't clear enough). I want to be able to specify the options like this: `<Field component={RenderSelect} >//Options</Field>`, not `<Field component={RenderSelect} someProp={options} />`, because to me the first syntax seems more natural (more similar to HTML).

Comment: Understood. Updated! Sorry for the runaround. Everything you're doing is correct, you just passed an unneeded parameter :) It was staring right at us the whole time!

Comment: oh wow, it works haha. Thanks a bunch dude, you've been very helpful! I'll accept your answer.